# Send two GetMetadataDB activity output values to Foreach activity

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am trying to get output from two different GetMetadataDB activities and want to pass as item names to foreach activity.

[image]

Pipeline Code Snippet

```
{
    "name": "V1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata From Source",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedSourceFile",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems",
                        "itemName"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach source and target",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata from Target",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata From Source",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@union(activity('Get Metadata From Source').output.childItems, activity('Get Metadata From Target').output.childItems)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "ValidationNotebook",
                            "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "notebookPath": "/GetFilenames",
                                "baseParameters": {
                                    "sourcestgpath": {
                                        "value": "@concat('abfss://',activity('Get Metadata from Source').output.itemName,'@dqstg.dfs.core.windows.net/',item().name)",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "targetstgpath": {
                                        "value": "@concat('abfss://',activity('Get Metadata from Target').output.itemName,'@dqstg.dfs.core.windows.net/',item().name)",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "linkedServiceName": {
                                "referenceName": "AzureDatabricks1",
                                "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata from Target",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedTargetFiles",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems",
                        "itemName"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "recursive": true
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Pipeline fails with error:

> {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The expression 'activity('Get Metadata From Source').output @activity('Get Metadata from Target').output' is not valid: the string character '@' at position '44' is not expected.\"","target":"pipeline/V1/runid/1457","details":null}}

How can this be achieved?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
@union(activity('Get Metadata From Source').output.childItems, activity('Get Metadata From Target').output.childItems)
```

Comment: adding this section to items...throws error after pipeline execution as : Operation on target ForEach source and target failed: The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.

Comment: @Amruta can you post the output of the Get Metadata activities? It could be .output is not the array

Comment: @Amruta I made an edit which I suspect will work. But please do post the output of the first two activities if not.

Comment: @ GregGalloway - I have updated my question with actual pipeline code

Comment: Pipeline fails while execution

Comment: A simplified version seems to be working for me. What do you get in the output of the first two activities when you run the pipeline in debug mode? https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7OUU.png

Comment: After trigger, For two metadata activities....foreach activity gets triggered twice....we changed the approach after the output....we have removed foreach activity..